# How to make concurrent rest requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

Hi I am trying to write an integration test which will make concurrent (say 3 concurrent for example) restful api calls, and I need to assert the data returned in each call is different.  This is because I have a find and update and return data within a synchronized block,so I need to test the data returned is different for each thread.  I have looked at the junit activetestsuite but unsure how to apply this to my integration test. API call i want to make in my IT test is below

```
  ResponseEntity<String> response = this.restTemplate
                .exchange("endpoint/",HttpMethod.GET,String.class);

 //make assertions on each returned call
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at ReactiveX **zip** method for Java:

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you would like to run the UnitTest concurrently. The Concurrent JUnit can help on this. https://github.com/ThomasKrieger/concurrent-junit 
There is also a step-by-step guide line in here: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/junit-multithreaded-test-example/

Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want to do this without having to add any further dependencies. Also I need to check the content of each call made and not just after all threads have been ran